# Prawn: Print unicode string in PDF

Tags: ruby, unicode, character-encoding, prawn

I'm using Prawn to generate PDFs in a Rails 3 app.

Is it possible to print a Unicode string into a PDF like in a HTML view?

For example,

```
<%= raw "unicode_for_&#x0F40;" %>
```

in `show.html.erb` results in the glyph ཀ while

```
pdf.text raw "unicode_for_&#x0F40;"
```

in `show.pdf.prawn` results in the string `"unicode_for_&#x0F40;"`

Tried in `show.pdf.prawn`:

```
    pdf.font "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/fonts/TibMachUni-1.901b.ttf" do
      pdf.text raw "unicode_for_&#x0F40;"
    end
```

and

```
    pdf.font_families.update("TibMachUni" => {:normal => "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/fonts/TibMachUni-1.901b.ttf" })
    pdf.font("TibMachUni") do 
      pdf.text raw "unicode_for_&#x0F40;"
    end
```

This did not solve the problem.

Comment: i really don't understand what the problem is?

Comment: My problem is that the corresponding glyph to the unicode string (e.g. \x0F40) is not showing up in my pdf. It gets simply converted to utf-8 and displayed as a regular string (e.g. "\x0F40").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use

```
pdf.text raw "unicode_for_\u0F40"
```

instead of

```
pdf.text raw "unicode_for_&#x0F40;"
```

The Ruby way to escape unicode characters is `\uXXXX`.

The `&#x0F40;` escape is an HTML/XML escape code and works only because the first view generated an HTML file.

Comment: The way to say thank you is to upvote and accept the answer ;)