# Using Unicode Character 'HEAVY CHECK MARK' (U+2714)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unicode

I know there so many question about it, but I just still don't get it after all on how I using it. I want to use [this Unicode Character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2714/index.htm) on my Controller like:

```
mutation = that Unicode Character;
```

I done trying several ways like:

```
mutation = &#x2714;
mutation = "#{&#x2714}";
mutation = "#{U+x2714}";
mutation = U+x2714;
mutation = "#{&#x2714}";
mutation = "#{\ux2714}";
```

But all still doesn't give me any success.

My *application.rb*

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

*note: I'm not using `iconv` because it always tell about deprecated soon and my boss tell me not to use it. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I really sorry if there any wrong word I used, in fact somehow I confuse about `Unicode Character` and `ASCII` one. Rails Newbie :(

Comment: I also done trying to use `&#10004;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: `mutation = "\u2714"`

Comment: Wow, that a miss for me. Hehe, any sir @brad-werth that yes indeed success on my html view, but why on my pdf report with prawn just become `_` ?

Comment: I had changed it but it same sir, what suppose I do?

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231302/prawn-print-unicode-string-in-pdf Not sure, it's a bit of a different issue...

Comment: The result was the same one, hehe. Anw thanks for your help at the html part, it was a great help!